# Is there a tool that can capture an OpenGL frame on MacOSX

Tags: macos, opengl

I am developing on MacOSX. The rendering result is unexpected. I hope to capture a frame to see the detail about the mesh and texture. And it's best that I can get the rendering history of a pixel.

I know that we can capture a frame on OpenGL ES. But I don't find the same tool for OpenGL.
The OpenGL profiler in Graphics Tools for XCode can give me the current state and resource when a breakpoint is hit, but it can not capture a frame.

So is there a tool that can capture an OpenGL frame on MacOSX?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: define 'capture', you could always [read the back buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157646/how-to-render-offscreen-on-opengl/12159293#12159293)

Comment: Sorry. I want to get the rendering history of a pixel for each draw command. And it's best that I can debug into the shader. I think glReadPixels can not do this.