# Object detection in WebApp

Tags: javascript, android, html, opencv

I am from Android development background so knows very less about webapps. I am working on a document detection functionality which i have achieved on Mobile app side using the following library project.

https://github.com/ctodobom/OpenNoteScanner

In the code `Custom Camera Api` is being used which provides the                     real-time camera frames which are then passed to `openCv`. From there `openCv` detects the document edges and returns the points which are used to draw the detected edges on a canvas.

The **Problem** here is we need the same functionality in `WebApp`.So please suggest the following.

1. Can we create custom camera using `Camera Api` in `webApps`.?

    if, yes then
2. How to get the `real-time camera frames` in `webApps`

What i have found so far.

Following is the link to a source code which opens a camera in mobile web browser. It is using `WebRtc`. But i am not able to find a way to grab the frames.

https://github.com/apal21/stream-user-video-from-device-webrtc

Comment: Will you be streaming the frames to server for processing?

Comment: Nop, For document detection, i will be using openCV at client end. Yet need to figure out the same as well.

Comment: Well OpenCV can be built with `gstreamer` support. Gstreamer can open your camera and capture frames in real time. You can use it to stream frames locally or to the server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810640/gstreamer-tcpserversink-v0-10-vs-1-0-and-html5-video-tag https://coaxion.net/blog/2013/10/streaming-gstreamer-pipelines-via-http/ https://gist.github.com/tetkuz/0c038321d05586841897