# How to convert raw BGRA image to JPG using GStreamer 1.0?

Tags: image, converters, gstreamer, gst-launch

I'm trying to display a [**raw** image (1.8MB)](http://www.filedropper.com/dumped) with `gst-launch-1.0`. I understand that the data needs to be encoded to JPG before this can be achieve. If image was already stored as a **jpg** file the story would be quite simple:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=output.jpg ! decodebin ! imagefreeze ! autovideosink
```

[image]

However, I need to assemble the pipeline to display a [raw **BGRA** 800x600 image](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00244733700414598735) (looks the same as the above) that was dumped to the disk by a 3D application.

This is what I've done so far, but the problem is that it creates a completely black image on the disk:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=dumped.bin ! video/x-raw,format=BGRA,width=800,height=600,framerate=1/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,framerate=1/1 ! jpegenc ! filesink location=out.jpg
```

Can GStreamer handle this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved!** The 2 major issues I faced were:

- **dump.bin** was a symlink on my system (Cygwin) and for some reason `gst-launch-1.0` was unable to work with it;
- When working with raw data, one **MUST** specify the **blocksize** for `filesrc`.

❄

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=dumped.bin blocksize=1920000 ! video/x-raw,format=BGRA,width=800,height=600,framerate=1/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,framerate=1/1 ! jpegenc ! filesink location=out.jpg
```

On this specific case I also needed to flip the image vertically because it was [captured from the OpenGL framebuffer of a 3D application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26934891/176769):

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=dumped.bin blocksize=1920000 ! video/x-raw,format=BGRA,width=800,height=600,framerate=1/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,framerate=1/1 ! videoflip method=vertical-flip ! jpegenc ! filesink location=out.jpg
```