# draw in FrameBuffer but get only black

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, glew

windows

using glew

I'm trying to render offscreen and save the img opengl rendered to a png file.

I followed a highly rated answer on stackoverflow: 
[How to render offscreen on OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157646/how-to-render-offscreen-on-opengl)

But the png file I get is only a black screen.

Here's my code relating to it:

```
glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
if(GLEW_OK!=glewInit())
{
    return -1;
}

initScene();


GLuint fbo, render_buf;
glGenFramebuffers(1,&fbo);
glGenRenderbuffers(1,&render_buf);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,render_buf);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB8, viewport.w, viewport.h);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, render_buf);


//Before drawing
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);


glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);               // clear the color buffer
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                 // indicate we are specifying camera transformations
glLoadIdentity();                       // make sure transformation is "zero'd"

//draw...
//glBegin(GL_POINTS) glColor3f, glVertex2f

//glFlush();
glFinish();

/*glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
glutPostRedisplay();*/

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
savePNG(outputPNGName,0,0,viewport.w,viewport.h);

//At deinit:
glDeleteFramebuffers(1,&fbo);
glDeleteRenderbuffers(1,&render_buf);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
```

How to solve the problem?
Thank you

---

savePNG (related code):

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)image);
```

Comment: Have to tried rendering onto a texture and display a quad with it in your scene? Would be good to make sure your framebuffer is working.

Comment: Also ensure - by leaving the system framebuffer active - that you really draw anything visible (happens all the time...) ;) If this and @Iggy 's solution don't help use e.g. [gDebugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) to have a look into your renderbuffer contents to be sure your savePNG is not the problem...

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my savePNG code...  @lggy can you share a link on how to render to texture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two problems in this code:

- `GL_RGB8` is not a valid format for a renderbuffer. From the [`glRenderbufferStorage()` man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glRenderbufferStorage.xhtml):

  > internalformat specifies the internal format to be used for the renderbuffer object's storage and must be a color-renderable, depth-renderable, or stencil-renderable format.

  Table 8.13 in the latest spec document (4.5, downloadable from https://www.opengl.org/registry) lists all formats, with a column showing which of them are color-renderable. `RGB8` does not have a checkmark in that column. You can use `GL_RGBA8` instead, which is color-renderable.

  You may also want to check out the `glCheckFramebufferStatus()` function, which allows you to check if your framebuffer setup is valid.
- While we don't see the code for `savePNG()`, there is no way it can know that you want to read the pixel data from your FBO. It will most likely use `glReadPixels()`, which reads data from the current read framebuffer, while your code only sets the draw framebuffer. Before calling `savePNG()`, add this call to set the read framebuffer to your FBO:

  ```
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the related code in savePNG, I've also corrected the site I followed. I've changed `GL_RGBA8` but still not working. The `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` returns 36053

Comment: @shrekshao: You should always print out OpenGL enum values in hexadecimal, that will make looking them up a lot easier. In this case, that corresponds to **0x8CD5**, which is `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`. Nobody's going to know what that number is by itself though, especially in base-10 ;)

Comment: 36053 is `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`, so that part should be fine. If you set the read framebuffer, you should be getting data. Also make sure that your `viewport.w` and `viewport.h` values are correct.

Comment: Thanks. viewport.w = 400 , viewport.h =400, I get a 400x400 png . I think this part is right. But my image is still black. Is the problem within my drawing part? I only use `glBegin(GL_POINT)`, `glColor3f`, `glVertex2f` in drawing @RetoKoradi

Comment: Try setting the clear color to something other than black, using `glClearColor()`. Then you'll see if the reading works without needing any drawing. Did you bind `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes, the `glClearColor()` works. I saw the change in the color in the output image. And I do bind `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`. So the problem is with the drawing? I might try some other drawing commands. Thanks.