# Convert S3TC / DXTn data to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have joined a project to simplify legacy graphics code, and would be grateful for advice on this data conversion problem.

The input is compressed textures in DXT1, DXT3, DXT5 formats. The data is in main memory, not graphics card memory. The input does not have the standard  [DDS_HEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943982(v=vs.85).aspx), only the compressed pixel data. The desired output is QImages.

Using existing metadata, we can construct a DDS_HEADER, write the texture to a temporary file, then load the QImage from that file. However we want to avoid this solution and work with the original data directly as there are many, many instances of it.

My research has uncovered no Qt functions to perform this conversion directly. So far, the most promising sounding approach is to use our existing OpenGL context to draw the texture to a QOpenGLFrameBufferObject. This class has a toImage() member function. However, I don't understand how to construct a usable texture object out of the raw data and draw that to the frame buffer.

**Edit:** A clarification, based on Scheff's excellent answer.  I am aware that the textures can be manually decompressed and a QImage loaded from the result. I would prefer to avoid this step and use library functions if possible, for greatest simplicity. QOpenGLTexture has a member function setCompressedData that might be used.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I had the idea that there should be resp. code in the Qt repositories. I looked a bit around at [woboq.org](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/). I am a bit uncertain whether `QImage` already contains such a decoder, or uses a plug-in, or even uses the data as is with a resp. format specifier. Finally, I was not able to locate the resp. code answering this and gave up.

Comment: Qt apparently used to include DDS loader for QImage, but only directly from a file with the DDS_HEADER. This is still optionally available but not included by default for security reasons. That functionality would unfortunately not provide the cleanest solution to rendering the in-memory data. This is what my mention of temporary files was about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I got the feed-back, that I didn't match the expectations of the questioner in [my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48136780/7478597), I modified my sources to draw the DXT1 raw-data into an OpenGL texture.

So, *this* answer addresses specifically this part of the question:

> However, I don't understand how to construct a usable texture object out of the raw data and draw that to the frame buffer.

The modifications are strongly "inspired" by the Qt docs [Cube OpenGL ES 2.0 example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html).

The essential part is how the `QOpenGLTexture` is constructed out of the DXT1 raw data:

```
      _pQGLTex = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
      _pQGLTex->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGB_DXT1);
      _pQGLTex->setSize(_img.w, _img.h);
      _pQGLTex->allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8);
      _pQGLTex->setCompressedData((int)_img.data.size(), _img.data.data());

      _pQGLTex->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
      _pQGLTex->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
      _pQGLTex->setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::ClampToEdge);
```

And, this is the complete sample code `DXT1-QTexture-QImage.cc`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_0_Core>

#ifndef _WIN32
typedef quint32 DWORD;
#endif // _WIN32

/* borrowed from:
 * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943984(v=vs.85).aspx
 */
struct DDS_PIXELFORMAT {
  DWORD dwSize;
  DWORD dwFlags;
  DWORD dwFourCC;
  DWORD dwRGBBitCount;
  DWORD dwRBitMask;
  DWORD dwGBitMask;
  DWORD dwBBitMask;
  DWORD dwABitMask;
};
/* borrowed from:
 * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943982(v=vs.85).aspx
 */
struct DDS_HEADER {
  DWORD           dwSize;
  DWORD           dwFlags;
  DWORD           dwHeight;
  DWORD           dwWidth;
  DWORD           dwPitchOrLinearSize;
  DWORD           dwDepth;
  DWORD           dwMipMapCount;
  DWORD           dwReserved1[11];
  DDS_PIXELFORMAT ddspf;
  DWORD           dwCaps;
  DWORD           dwCaps2;
  DWORD           dwCaps3;
  DWORD           dwCaps4;
  DWORD           dwReserved2;
};

struct Image {
  int w, h;
  std::vector<std::uint8_t> data;

  explicit Image(int w = 0, int h = 0):
    w(w), h(h), data(((w + 3) / 4) * ((h + 3) / 4) * 8)
  { }
  ~Image() = default;
  Image(const Image&) = delete;
  Image& operator=(const Image&) = delete;
  Image(Image &&img): w(img.w), h(img.h), data(move(img.data)) { }
};

Image loadDXT1(const char *file)
{
  std::ifstream fIn(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  // read magic code
  enum { sizeMagic = 4 }; char magic[sizeMagic];
  if (!fIn.read(magic, sizeMagic)) {
    return Image(); // ERROR: read failed
  }
  if (strncmp(magic, "DDS ", sizeMagic) != 0) {
    return Image(); // ERROR: wrong format (wrong magic code)
  }
  // read header
  DDS_HEADER header;
  if (!fIn.read((char*)&header, sizeof header)) {
    return Image(); // ERROR: read failed
  }
  qDebug() << "header size:" << sizeof header;
  // get raw data (size computation unclear)
  Image img(header.dwWidth, header.dwHeight);
  qDebug() << "data size:" << img.data.size();
  if (!fIn.read((char*)img.data.data(), img.data.size())) {
    return Image(); // ERROR: read failed
  }
  qDebug() << "processed image size:" << fIn.tellg();
  // done 
  return img;
}

const char *vertexShader =
  "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
  "// Set default precision to medium\n"
  "precision mediump int;\n"
  "precision mediump float;\n"
  "#endif\n"
  "\n"
  "uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;\n"
  "\n"
  "attribute vec4 a_position;\n"
  "attribute vec2 a_texcoord;\n"
  "\n"
  "varying vec2 v_texcoord;\n"
  "\n"
  "void main()\n"
  "{\n"
  "  // Calculate vertex position in screen space\n"
  "  gl_Position = mvp_matrix * a_position;\n"
  "\n"
  "  // Pass texture coordinate to fragment shader\n"
  "  // Value will be automatically interpolated to fragments inside polygon faces\n"
  "  v_texcoord = a_texcoord;\n"
  "}\n";

const char *fragmentShader =
  "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
  "// Set default precision to medium\n"
  "precision mediump int;\n"
  "precision mediump float;\n"
  "#endif\n"
  "\n"
  "uniform sampler2D texture;\n"
  "\n"
  "varying vec2 v_texcoord;\n"
  "\n"
  "void main()\n"
  "{\n"
  "  // Set fragment color from texture\n"
  "#if 0 // test check tex coords\n"
  "  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, v_texcoord.x, v_texcoord.y, 1);\n"
  "#else // (not) 0;\n"
  "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, v_texcoord);\n"
  "#endif // 0\n"
  "}\n";

 struct Vertex {
   QVector3D coord;
   QVector2D texCoord;
   Vertex(qreal x, qreal y, qreal z, qreal s, qreal t):
     coord(x, y, z), texCoord(s, t)
   { }
 };

class OpenGLWidget: public QOpenGLWidget, public QOpenGLFunctions_4_0_Core {
  private:
    const Image &_img;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram _qGLSProg;
    QOpenGLBuffer _qGLBufArray;
    QOpenGLBuffer _qGLBufIndex;
    QOpenGLTexture *_pQGLTex;

  public:
    explicit OpenGLWidget(const Image &img):
      QOpenGLWidget(nullptr),
      _img(img),
      _qGLBufArray(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer),
      _qGLBufIndex(QOpenGLBuffer::IndexBuffer),
      _pQGLTex(nullptr)
    { }
    virtual ~OpenGLWidget()
    {
      makeCurrent();
      delete _pQGLTex;
      _qGLBufArray.destroy();
      _qGLBufIndex.destroy();
      doneCurrent();
    }
    // disabled: (to prevent accidental usage)
    OpenGLWidget(const OpenGLWidget&) = delete;
    OpenGLWidget& operator=(const OpenGLWidget&) = delete;

  protected:
    virtual void initializeGL() override
    {
      initializeOpenGLFunctions();
      glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
      initShaders();
      initGeometry();
      initTexture();
    }
    virtual void paintGL() override
    {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      _pQGLTex->bind();
      QMatrix4x4 mat; mat.setToIdentity();
      _qGLSProg.setUniformValue("mvp_matrix", mat);
      _qGLSProg.setUniformValue("texture", 0);
      // draw geometry
      _qGLBufArray.bind();
      _qGLBufIndex.bind();
      quintptr offset = 0;
      int coordLocation = _qGLSProg.attributeLocation("a_position");
      _qGLSProg.enableAttributeArray(coordLocation);
      _qGLSProg.setAttributeBuffer(coordLocation, GL_FLOAT, offset, 3, sizeof(Vertex));
      offset += sizeof(QVector3D);
      int texCoordLocation = _qGLSProg.attributeLocation("a_texcoord");
      _qGLSProg.enableAttributeArray(texCoordLocation);
      _qGLSProg.setAttributeBuffer(texCoordLocation, GL_FLOAT, offset, 2, sizeof(Vertex));
      glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
      //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }

  private:
    void initShaders()
    {
      if (!_qGLSProg.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
        QString::fromLatin1(vertexShader))) close();
      if (!_qGLSProg.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
        QString::fromLatin1(fragmentShader))) close();
      if (!_qGLSProg.link()) close();
      if (!_qGLSProg.bind()) close();
    }
    void initGeometry()
    {
      Vertex vertices[] = {
        //  x      y      z     s     t
        { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
        { +1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
        { +1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { -1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }
      };
      enum { nVtcs = sizeof vertices / sizeof *vertices };
      // OpenGL ES doesn't have QUAD. A TRIANGLE_STRIP does as well.
      GLushort indices[] = { 3, 0, 2, 1 };
      //GLushort indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
      enum { nIdcs = sizeof indices / sizeof *indices };
      _qGLBufArray.create();
      _qGLBufArray.bind();
      _qGLBufArray.allocate(vertices, nVtcs * sizeof (Vertex));
      _qGLBufIndex.create();
      _qGLBufIndex.bind();
      _qGLBufIndex.allocate(indices, nIdcs * sizeof (GLushort));
    }
    void initTexture()
    {
#if 0 // test whether texturing works at all
      //_pQGLTex = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage("test.png").mirrored());
      _pQGLTex = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage("test-dxt1.dds").mirrored());
#else // (not) 0
      _pQGLTex = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
      _pQGLTex->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGB_DXT1);
      _pQGLTex->setSize(_img.w, _img.h);
      _pQGLTex->allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8);
      _pQGLTex->setCompressedData((int)_img.data.size(), _img.data.data());
#endif // 0
      _pQGLTex->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
      _pQGLTex->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
      _pQGLTex->setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::ClampToEdge);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // load a DDS image to get DTX1 raw data
  Image img = loadDXT1("test-dxt1.dds");
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  OpenGLWidget qGLView(img);
  /* I apply brute-force to get main window to sufficient size
   * -> not appropriate for a productive solution...
   */
  qGLView.setMinimumSize(img.w, img.h);
  qWin.setCentralWidget(&qGLView);
  qWin.show();
  // exec. application
  return app.exec();
}
```

For the test, I used (again) the sample file [`test-dxt1.dds`](https://github.com/toji/webgl-texture-utils/blob/master/sample/img/test-dxt1.dds).

And this is, how it looks (sample compiled with VS2013 and Qt 5.9.2):

[image: Snapshot of DXT1-QTexture-QImage]

**Notes:**

1. The texture is displayed upside-down. Please, consider that the original sample as well as my (excluded) code for texture loading from `QImage` applies a `QImage::mirror()`. It seems that `QImage` stores the data from top to bottom where OpenGL textures expect the opposite – from bottom to top. I guess the most easy would be to fix this after the texture is converted back to `QImage`.
2. My original intention was to implement also the part to read the texture back to a `QImage` (as described/sketched in the question). In general, I already did something like this in OpenGL (but without Qt). (I recently posted another answer [OpenGL offscreen render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48049881/7478597) about this. I have to admit that I had to cancel this plan due to a "time-out" issue. This was caused by some issues for which I needed quite long until I could fix them. I will share this experiences in the following as I'm thinking this could be helpful for others.
3. To find sample code for the initialization of the `QOpenGLTexture` with DXT1 data, I did a long google research – without success. Hence, I eye-scanned the Qt doc. of `QOpenGLTexture` for methods which looked promising/nessary to get it working. (I have to admit that I already did OpenGL texturing successfully but in pure OpenGL.) Finally, I got the actual set of necessary functions. It compiled and started but all I got was a black window. (Everytimes, I start something new with OpenGL it first ends up in a black or blue window – depending on what clear color I used resp...) So, I had a look into the [`qopengltexture.cpp`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/opengl/qopengltexture.cpp.html) on woboq.org (specifically in the implementation of `QOpenGLTexture::QOpenGLTexture(QImage&, ...)`). This didn't help much – they do it very similar as I tried.
4. The most essential problem, I could fix discussing this program with a colleague who contributed the final hint: I tried to get this running using `QOpenGLFunctions`. The last steps (toward the final fix) were trying this out with
   `_pQGLTex = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage("test.png").mirrored());`
   (worked) and
   `_pQGLTex = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage("test-dxt1.dds").mirrored());`
   (did not work).
   This brought as to the idea that [`QOpenGLFunctions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html) (which is claimed to be compatible to OpenGL ES 2.0) just seems not to enable S3 Texture loading. Hence, we replaced `QOpenGLFunctions` by [`QOpenGLFunctions_4_0_Core`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions-4-0-core.html) and, suddenly, it worked.
5. I did not overload the `QOpenGLWidget::resizeGL()` method as I use an identity matrix for the model-view-projection transformation of the OpenGL rendering. This is intended to have model space and clip space identical. Instead, I built a rectangle (-1, -1, 0) - (+1, +1, 0) which should exactly fill the (visible part of) the clip space x-y plane (and it does).
6. This can be checked visually by enabling the left-in debug code in the shader
   `gl_FragColor = vec4(1, v_texcoord.x, v_texcoord.y, 1);`
   which uses texture coordinates itself as green and blue color component. This makes a nice colored rectangle with red in the lower-left corner, magenta (red and blue) in the upper-left, yellow (red and green) in the lower-right, and white (red, green, and blue) in the upper-right corner. It shows that the rectangle fits perfectly.
7. As I forced the minimum size of the `OpenGLWidget` to the exact size of the texture image the texture to pixel mapping should be 1:1. I checked out what happens if magnification is set to `Nearest` – there was no visual difference.
8. I have to admit that the DXT1 data rendered as texture looks much better than the decompression I've exposed in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48136780/7478597). Considering, that these are the exact same data (read by my nearly identical loader) this let me think my own uncompress algorithm does not yet consider something (in other words: it still seems to be buggy). Hmm... (It seems that needs additional fixing.)

Comment: Thank you for the very promising answer. This is exactly the most suitable kind of approach. I am testing at present, and receive OpenGL error 1281 (bad value) on _pQGLTex->allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8);  I am surprised by this, but hope I can track the problem down soon. The problem occurs with no modifications to your code.

Comment: Bad value... Damn. I replaced the sample code as I recognized some left trash. The new sample code is exactly what I just compiled and ran in VS2013. (No editing of code while writing the answer...) Btw. I tried this code in cygwin as well. It started, loaded the file, but then it died with `failed to create drawable` and `QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current`. Hmm. Is this my code or is it cygwin? (I don't know.)

Comment: The problem was solved by enclosing the initTexture() function in makeCurrent() and doneCurrent(). This surprises me but I'll try to understand why later! My question has now been fully answered, and I foresee others finding it useful too. Thank you.

Comment: [`makeCurrent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#makeCurrent) (and `doneCurrent()`) calls have always to enclose GL related functions so that the corresponding OpenGL context is activated. In my case, I called `initTexture()` out of [`QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#initializeGL) where the context is made current before.

Answer (score 3):

Reading this question, I became curious and learnt about [S3 Texture Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression). Funny enough, although I heart about compressed textures in the past, I always assumed that it would be something complicated like [LZW Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) or [JPEG Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression), and never digged deeper. But, today I realized I was totally wrong.

[S3 Texture Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression) is actually much simpler though it can achieve quite impressive compression ratios.

Nice introductions can be easily found by google. The question already mentions MSDN. Additionally, I found some other sites which gave me a quite good introduction into this topic in least time:

- khronos.org: [S3 Texture Compression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression) (which I consider as authoritative source)
- FSDeveloper.com: [DXT compression explained](http://www.fsdeveloper.com/wiki/index.php?title=DXT_compression_explained)
- Joost's Dev Blog: [Texture formats for 2D games, part 3: DXT and PVRTC](http://joostdevblog.blogspot.de/2015/11/texture-formats-for-2d-games-part-3-dxt.html)
- MSDN: [Programming Guide for DDS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943991(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Brandon Jones [webgl-texture-utils](https://github.com/toji/webgl-texture-utils) on GitHub
- nv_dds on GitHub [DDS image loader for OpenGL/ OpenGL ES2](https://github.com/paroj/nv_dds).

Concerning the GitHub projects, it seems that somebodies already did the work. I scanned a little bit the code by eyes but, finally, I'm not sure whether they support all possible features. However, I "borrowed" the test images from Brandon Jones site, so, it's fair enough to mention it.

So, this is my actual answer: An alternative approach could be to decode of texture to the QImage on CPU side completely.

As a proof of concept, I leave the result of my code fiddling I did this morning – my trial to transform the linked descriptions into working C++ code – `DXT1-QImage.cc`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>

#include <QtWidgets>

#ifndef _WIN32
typedef quint32 DWORD;
#endif // _WIN32

/* borrowed from:
 * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943984(v=vs.85).aspx
 */
struct DDS_PIXELFORMAT {
  DWORD dwSize;
  DWORD dwFlags;
  DWORD dwFourCC;
  DWORD dwRGBBitCount;
  DWORD dwRBitMask;
  DWORD dwGBitMask;
  DWORD dwBBitMask;
  DWORD dwABitMask;
};
/* borrowed from:
 * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943982(v=vs.85).aspx
 */
struct DDS_HEADER {
  DWORD           dwSize;
  DWORD           dwFlags;
  DWORD           dwHeight;
  DWORD           dwWidth;
  DWORD           dwPitchOrLinearSize;
  DWORD           dwDepth;
  DWORD           dwMipMapCount;
  DWORD           dwReserved1[11];
  DDS_PIXELFORMAT ddspf;
  DWORD           dwCaps;
  DWORD           dwCaps2;
  DWORD           dwCaps3;
  DWORD           dwCaps4;
  DWORD           dwReserved2;
};

inline quint32 stretch(std::uint16_t color)
{
  return 0xff000000u
    | (quint32)(color & 0x001f) << 3 // >>  0 << 3 <<  0
    | (quint32)(color & 0x07e0) << 5 // >>  5 << 2 <<  8
    | (quint32)(color & 0xf800) << 8;// >> 11 << 3 << 16
}

void makeLUT(
  quint32 lut[4], std::uint16_t color0, std::uint16_t color1)
{
  const quint32 argb0 = stretch(color0);
  const quint32 argb1 = stretch(color1);
  lut[0] = argb0;
  lut[1] = argb1;
  if (color0 > color1) {
    lut[2] = 0xff000000u
      | ((((argb0 & 0xff0000) >> 15) + ((argb1 & 0xff0000) >> 16)) / 3) << 16
      | ((((argb0 & 0x00ff00) >>  7) + ((argb1 & 0x00ff00) >>  8)) / 3) <<  8
      | ((((argb0 & 0x0000ff) <<  1) + ((argb1 & 0x0000ff) >>  0)) / 3) <<  0;
    lut[3] = 0xff000000u
      | ((((argb1 & 0xff0000) >> 15) + ((argb0 & 0xff0000) >> 16)) / 3) << 16
      | ((((argb1 & 0x00ff00) >>  7) + ((argb0 & 0x00ff00) >>  8)) / 3) <<  8
      | ((((argb1 & 0x0000ff) <<  1) + ((argb0 & 0x0000ff) >>  0)) / 3) <<  0;
  } else {
    lut[2] = 0xff000000u
      | ((((argb0 & 0xff0000) >> 16) + ((argb1 & 0xff0000) >> 16)) / 2) << 16
      | ((((argb0 & 0x00ff00) >>  8) + ((argb1 & 0x00ff00) >>  8)) / 2) <<  8
      | ((((argb0 & 0x0000ff) >>  0) + ((argb1 & 0x0000ff) >>  0)) / 2) <<  0;
    lut[3] = 0xff000000u;
  }
}

const std::uint8_t* uncompress(
  const std::uint8_t *data, QImage &qImg, int x, int y)
{
  // get color 0 and color 1
  std::uint16_t color0 = data[0] | data[1] << 8;
  std::uint16_t color1 = data[2] | data[3] << 8;
  data += 4;
  quint32 lut[4]; makeLUT(lut, color0, color1);
  // decode 4 x 4 pixels
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    qImg.setPixel(x + 0, y + i, lut[data[i] >> 0 & 3]);
    qImg.setPixel(x + 1, y + i, lut[data[i] >> 2 & 3]);
    qImg.setPixel(x + 2, y + i, lut[data[i] >> 4 & 3]);
    qImg.setPixel(x + 3, y + i, lut[data[i] >> 6 & 3]);
  }
  data += 4;
  // done
  return data;
}

QImage loadDXT1(const char *file)
{
  std::ifstream fIn(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  // read magic code
  enum { sizeMagic = 4 }; char magic[sizeMagic];
  if (!fIn.read(magic, sizeMagic)) {
    return QImage(); // ERROR: read failed
  }
  if (strncmp(magic, "DDS ", sizeMagic) != 0) {
    return QImage(); // ERROR: wrong format (wrong magic code)
  }
  // read header
  DDS_HEADER header;
  if (!fIn.read((char*)&header, sizeof header)) {
    return QImage(); // ERROR: read failed
  }
  qDebug() << "header size:" << sizeof header;
  // get raw data (size computation unclear)
  const unsigned w = (header.dwWidth + 3) / 4;
  const unsigned h = (header.dwHeight + 3) / 4;
  std::vector<std::uint8_t> data(w * h * 8);
  qDebug() << "data size:" << data.size();
  if (!fIn.read((char*)data.data(), data.size())) {
    return QImage(); // ERROR: read failed
  }
  // decode raw data
  QImage qImg(header.dwWidth, header.dwHeight, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
  const std::uint8_t *pData = data.data();
  for (int y = 0; y < (int)header.dwHeight; y += 4) {
    for (int x = 0; x < (int)header.dwWidth; x += 4) {
      pData = uncompress(pData, qImg, x, y);
    }
  }
  qDebug() << "processed image size:" << fIn.tellg();
  // done 
  return qImg;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // build QImage
  QImage qImg = loadDXT1("test-dxt1.dds");
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  QLabel qLblImg;
  qLblImg.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImg));
  qWin.setCentralWidget(&qLblImg);
  qWin.show();
  // exec. application
  return app.exec();
}
```

I did the development and debugging on VS2013. To check out, whether it is portable to Linux the best I could do was to compile and test on cygwin as well.

For this, I wrote a QMake file `DXT1-QImage.pro`:

```
SOURCES = DXT1-QImage.cc

QT += widgets
```

to compile and run this in `bash`:

```
$ qmake-qt5 DXT1-QImage.pro 

$ make
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o DXT1-QImage.o DXT1-QImage.cc
g++  -o DXT1-QImage.exe DXT1-QImage.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

$ ./DXT1-QImage 
Qt Version: 5.9.2
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-ds32737'
header size: 124
data size: 131072
processed image size: 131200
QXcbShmImage: shmget() failed (88: Function not implemented) for size 1048576 (512x512)
```

For the test, I used the sample file [test-dxt1.dds](https://github.com/toji/webgl-texture-utils/blob/master/sample/img/test-dxt1.dds).

And this is what came out:
[image: Snapshot of DXT1-QImage]

For comparison, the original image:

[image: the test image as PNG]

**Notes:**

I'm implemented a file loader although the questioner explicitly mentioned that he wants to convert raw image data which is already in memory. I had to do this as I didn't see any other way to get (valid) DXT1 raw data into memory on my side (to justify afterwards if it works or not).

My debug output shows that my loader reads 131200 bytes (i.e. 4 bytes magic code, 124 bytes header, and 131072 bytes compressed image data).
In opposition to this, the file [test-dxt1.dds](https://github.com/toji/webgl-texture-utils/blob/master/sample/img/test-dxt1.dds) contains 174904 bytes. So, there is additional data in file but I do not (yet) know for what it is good for.

Comment: Thank you for the effort you have put into this answer. No doubt it will be useful to others as well. I would prefer a solution that does not decompress the texture manually but loads it directly into one of Qt's texture wrappers, and renders to a buffer, because if possible, this would use very little code. Therefore I will leave the question open, but +1.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify my preference for a library solution over manual decompression. I hope you don't feel your effort was wasted! The answer is very useful nonetheless.

Comment: I finally found another link on khronos.org which described the encoding in more detail. So, I was able to fix the uncompressing. Result is looking much better know and I updated this answer resp.