# Can't draw on Framebuffer with Renderbuffer

Tags: c++, opengl

Hello i am trying to make an offscreen render with opengl. I already read answers to question [How to render offscreen on OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157646/how-to-render-offscreen-on-opengl). I set up everything like in top answer, but opengl doesn't draw on framebuffer. At least i can get data from it. There's example. What am i doing wrong?

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include "GL\freeglut.h"
#include <cstdio>

void RenderFunction(void);
GLuint fbo, render_buf;
unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[256 * 256 * 4]();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("Lel");

    glewInit();

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);                                                                        // 
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);                                                       // 
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &render_buf);                                                                // (1) Comment this section
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, render_buf);                                                   // 
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, 256, 256);                                         // 
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, render_buf); // 

    glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    glutMainLoop();
}

void RenderFunction(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);                  // (2) Comment first line and uncomment second
    //glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);                             // 
    glReadPixels(0, 0, 256, 256, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    printf("begin:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("end:\n");
    for (int i = 256 * 256 * 4 - 8; i < 256 * 256 * 4; i++) {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    //glutSwapBuffers();                        // (3) uncomment buffer swap
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing old and new OpenGL? I'd get rid of *glBegin, glColor4f, glVertex2f* and rest of OGL < 3.2 commands. Come on, jump into *shaders* era.

Comment: @Ripi2 Sorry but i am newbie in opengl and shaders stuff. So i choose the simplest way to do it. Also my task is super simple. Just draw bunch of 2d lines and save them as png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
> ```

You bind `fbo` as the *draw* framebuffer, but `glReadPixels` will always read from `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`. As a result, you do not get the contents of `fbo`, but of the default framebuffer, and `glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)` should actually produce `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error beause the default buffer has only the `GL_FRONT` and `GL_BACK` color buffers, and no generic color attachments.

Not that on many sources, you will see `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ...)` which is just a shortcut to bind `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` and `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` at once.

In general, checking for GL errors will help diagnosing such issues. Modern GL has [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) functionality which greatly improves usability and information density, so you should use this whenever possible.

Your code is also lacking a proper `glViewport` call mathcing your FBO size. Initially, the viewport will be set to the size of the window when the GL context is first bound to it.

Comment: Oh my god. I tried switching `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`, `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`, `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` so many times. And now it's finally works. Thank you! Also thanks for page about OpenGL debugging.